# Max Processes Limit is currently 31196 and It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption

Tags: apache, solr

i am trying to use ltr(learning to rank) in solr and following the steps as mentioned in  [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/learning-to-rank.html#quick-start-with-ltr)

when i run `bin/solr start -e techproducts -Dsolr.ltr.enabled=true`
it shows this error

```
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 31196. 
It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption. 
If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh.
```

I tried to increase the number of the process by `ulimit -u 65535` but it is denying the operation

```
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I am stuck at it and  can't find a solution if anyone knows please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen [ulimit PICKLE: “Operation not permitted” and “Command not found”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/ulimit-pickle-operation-not-permitted-and-command-not-found)?

Comment: I run sudo bash -c "ulimit -n 65535" command did ran but nothing happens

Comment: Yes, as explained - that will not work, as it only changes the limit for the bash shell invoked på sudo, and not for the system.

Comment: it's been done by changing the permission of solr

Comment: @VivekSingh How did you change the permission?

Comment: @harrrrrrry by running chmod command in sudo mode "sudo chmod  - R 777 solr-folder"

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command as root user. It will append the config to the limit file to make it work.

nofile is number of open file limit

nproc is number of process limit

```
# Increase number of open files. must be run as root
sudo su -
echo '* hard nofile 500000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo '* soft nofile 500000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo 'root hard nofile 500000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo 'root hard nofile 500000' >> /etc/security/limits.conf

echo 'fs.file-max = 2097152' >> /etc/sysctl.conf

# set the processes/threads limit
sudo vi /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf
# * soft nproc 122944
```

> Note: The Open file limit depends on the RAM size of your server
>
> For domain specific settings /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf will
> override /etc/security/limits.conf configurations.

> To make this work you should either reboot `sudo reboot` or close all active sessions windows because they would still remain in session.